# search names in mail address

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking for a query that match the exact name into a mail address.
The definition of *exact* match is when a name is part of email address:

- but not the in the domain (after the "@")
- is not a subset of a bigger name
- is not a subset when it's separated by non alphabetic characters (numbers, comma, dot, underscore, etc.)
- full match the local part (before the "@")

To clarify I've prepared some sample data:

table **names**

```
luis
mary
anne
andrew
```

table **mails**

```
luis.sepulveda@gmail.com
johnn@mary.com
jeanne.darc@gmail.com
smith_anne@example.com
mary1999@mail.com
andrew@hotmail.com
```

the query should return:

```
 luis luis.sepulveda@gmail.com 
 anne smith_anne@example.com 
 mary mary1999@mail.com 
 andrew andrew@hotmail.com
```

unfortunately the `SELECT` with `LIKE` operand returns a lot of false positive:

```
select name,address
from emails
join names on address like concat('%',name,'%');
```

I've prepared a [test environment on SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e080b/45)

Comment: *jeanne_darc* shold not match *anne*, so false positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a match in the portion of the email *before* the `@` (at the least).  You can handle this with `substring_index()` or a regular expression:

```
select n.name, e.address
from emails e join
     names n
     on substring_index(e.address, '@', 1 ) like concat('%', name, '%');
```

If you are trying for a match of an exact name, so "anne" does not match "jeanne", then take the periods into account:

```
select n.name, e.address
from emails e join
     names n
     on concat('.', substring_index(e.address, '@', 1 ), '.') like concat('%.', name, '.%');
```

This doesn't capture Anne, which you can do with regular expressions:

```
select n.name, e.address, concat('[^a-zA-Z]', name, '[^a-zA-Z].*@')
from emails e join
     names n
     on concat('.', e.address) regexp concat('[^a-zA-Z]', name, '[^a-zA-Z]?.*@')
```

Comment: it should take all the *non alphabetic characters (numbers, comma, dot, underscore, etc.)* as separator

Answer (score 0):

You can match name and the sub string of address before `@` of email table

```
select name,address
from emails
join names 
on SubString(address,1,POSITION('@' IN address)) like concat('%',name,'%');
```

Comment: version 1: unfortunately this miss *anne*, that is not at the begining of address

Comment: version 2: unfortunately this take *jeanne darc*

Answer (score 0):

For completeness starting from @GordonLinoff I landed to this query, may be redountant but cover all cases

```
select name,address
from emails e
join names on
lower(e.address) regexp concat('^(',name,'|[^a-z]*',name,'[^a-z]*'   ,'|[^@]+[^a-z]+' ,name, '[^a-z@]*'  ,'|[^@a-z]*' ,name, '[^a-z]+[^@]+'      ,')@')
```